# (Neo)vim substitute over block/regular visual range, and not line visual range

Tags: vim, neovim

If I highlight a block of text in visual mode in Vim and then press `:`, I can run a command on it. For example

- `:'<,'>s/foo/bar/g` to substitute,
- or `:'<,'> !bash` to send the lines to the `bash` shell and get the output,
- or `:'<,'>sort` to sort those lines,
- or `:'<,'> !some_cli_util` to send those lines to `some_cli_util`

This is fine if the text I want to execute is conveniently on it's own line, but often that isn't the case. For example, if I'm writing docs and want to give and example of a cli command and it's output, then it would be nice to just write:

```
$ head requirements.txt
```

and then to select the text `head requirements.txt`, type `: !sh<CR>`, and be given the actual output of the command. But in reality, when I select `head requirements.txt` and type `:`, then my selection gets expanded to a full-line selection, which causes the leading `$` to be clobbered in with the actual command, and so because of the leading `$`, the command fails.

A less trivial example of where this would be useful, is if I had a LaTeX table like:

```latex
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lllll}
        col1   & col2   & col3   & col4   & col5     \\

        foo19s & fook2e & foojd9 & alfooc & 9dfooj   \\
        9foo1s & ekfoo2 & lqfoo  & alfoo  & 9efoo9s  \\
        1sfoo9 & d9fooe & fooj9d & alsdfo & 9hfooje  \\
        19sfoo & 9dfooe & lqfoo  & dfoo9e & ajfoo   
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and I wanted to replace all the instances of `foo` with `bar`, but only in the columns titled `col2`. If I could block-select only `col2`, and then execute a substitute command like `` :`<,`>s/foo/bar/g `` then this would work. But currently, if I block select only `col2` and then press `:`, Vim will auto-select the entire range of lines that were in my block selection.

Ideally, I'd like vim to be smart enough such that if am in block-visual mode and press `:`, then it'll use the `` :`<,`> `` range selector, but if I'm in line-visual mode and press `:` then it'll use the `:'<,'>` range selector.

`` :h `< `` tells me that the  `` `< `` and  `` `> `` marks do exist, but I can't see how to apply them to commands.

What can I do to enable vim (or neovim) to execute commands on block-selections? or is there an issue open for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

> I can't just use the regular visual-line selector `:'<,'>s/ba/__/g` because that will incorrectly replace all the `baz`s with `__z`s.

Yes, you definitely can, but with a more refined search pattern:

```
:[range]s/ba\zer/__/g
```

See `:help \ze`.

--- EDIT ---

As explained in the other answer, Ex commands only work on *lines* and ranges are ranges of *lines*. You wont be able to pass something else than one or several lines to `:help :s`, `:help :range!` or `:help :sort`.

**There is no way around that**.

While the range of Ex commands is *always* linewise, some of them *may* honor the visual selection in some way.

In the case of `:help :s`, what you can do is, *again*, use a more refined search pattern:

```
<C-v><motions>
:[range]s/\%V.*\zsfoo\ze.*%V/bar
```

See `:help \%V`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is one of the "other means" I was talking about which can solve this MWE, but not the general problem. I want to be able to execute an arbitrary command on a block of text

Comment: That MWE is pointless if it doesn't accurately reflect the actual problem. Post a real example.

Comment: Sorry for the poor MWE, I underestimated the intricacies of what I was asking. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

How to get it done is described perfectly in romainl's answer. I'd like to answer the "why?", though.

You wrote:

> Ideally, I'd like vim to be smart enough such that if am in block-visual mode and press :, then it'll use the :`<,`> range selector, but if I'm in line-visual mode and press : then it'll use the :'<,'> range selector.

This behavior is explicitly impossible, at least for now (Vim 9.0). Quoting from `:h :visual_example`:

> Currently the ":" command works on whole lines only.  When you select part of
> a line, doing something like ":!date" will replace the whole line.  If you
> want only part of the line to be replaced you will have to make a mapping for
> it.  In a future release ":" may work on partial lines.

Likewise, `:h :s` says (emphasis mine):

> For each *line* in [range] replace a match of {pattern}

It is a common misconception that Vim would operate on the (block) visual selection only. Not all commands do. Instead, they operate on *lines* that are selected.

So you'll have to use a line-wise substitution like (as pointed out by romainl and included for the sake of completeness) `:s/ba\zer/__/g`.

Comment: Thanks for the references, that really helps. I'm gonna leave this question open for a while longer in case there is a different solution, but otherwise I'll accept that it's not possible

Comment: Since your MWE is not actually working, you might consider posting your actual text file and see if anyone comes up with a solution. You prevent meaningful answers by not showing your actual problem, ruling out plugins and narrowing solutions to one approach that's sadly not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's a reasonable tool to look for, but as others have pointed out, ranges are only line-wise. For the cases where you'd like to use a selection as an argument to an external program, I'd recommend yanking and pasting in the command-line.

A plugin that might give you a general-purpose solution is vis: https://github.com/vim-scripts/vis. Instead of `:'<,'>s/foo/bar/g`, you'd execute `:'<,'>B s/foo/bar/g`, which is less convenient, but will do the trick.